# Cannot set property 'indeterminate' of null in React

Tags: reactjs, html, checkbox

In my application, I need something like:

When a questions value is null then the checkbox should be shown as indeterminate, otherwise should be checked or not-checked.

But the problem is that when I update the questions, it shows me the error:

> TypeError: Cannot set property 'indeterminate' of null

My questions object in state is like this:

```
questions: [{
    id: 1,
    title: 'First Question',
    answers: [
        {
            id: 2,
            title: 'Java',
            value: ''
        },
        {
            id: 3,
            title: 'Python',
            value: ''
        },
        {
            id: 4,
            title: '.NET',
            value: true
        }
    ]
}]
```

So it means that the third checkbox should be checked, and other two should be shown as indeterminate. 
See picture below:

[image]

So when I click on the first one, it should become unchecked,and after clicking it again, its value should be true and should become checked. And their value will never be `''` ever, except that it can be the first time.

Here's the question.jsx

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Question extends Component {
    state = {
        questions: []
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        const questions = [{
            id: 1,
            title: 'First Question',
            answers: [
                {
                    id: 2,
                    title: 'Java',
                    value: ''
                },
                {
                    id: 3,
                    title: 'Python',
                    value: ''
                },
                {
                    id: 4,
                    title: '.NET',
                    value: true
                }
            ]
        }, {
            id: 2,
            title: 'Second Question',
            answers: [
                {
                    id: 5,
                    title: 'MongoDB',
                    value: ''
                },
                {
                    id: 6,
                    title: 'MSSQL',
                    value: ''
                },
                {
                    id: 7,
                    title: 'MySQL',
                    value: ''
                }
            ]
        }, {
            id: 3,
            title: 'Third Question',
            answers: [
                {
                    id: 8,
                    title: 'ReactJs',
                    value: ''
                },
                {
                    id: 9,
                    title: 'Angular',
                    value: ''
                },
                {
                    id: 10,
                    title: 'VueJs',
                    value: ''
                }
            ]
        }]
        this.setState({
            questions
        })
    }

    setIndeterminate = (elm, value) => {
        if (value !== '') {
            elm.checked = value;
            elm.indeterminate = false;
        }
        else {
            elm.checkbox = false;
            elm.indeterminate = true;
        }
    }

    handleOnChange = ({ currentTarget: checkbox }) => {
        var questions = [...this.state.questions];
        questions.map(p => {
            p.answers.map(a => {
                if (a.id == checkbox.id) {
                    a.value = (a.value === '') ? false : !a.value;
                    return;
                }
            })
        })

        this.setState({
            questions
        })
    }

    render() {
        const { questions } = this.state
        return (
            <div>
                {questions.map(question =>
                    <div key={question.id} className='question-wrapper'>
                        <div className="row">
                            <h6 className='text-left'>{question.title}</h6>
                        </div>
                        {question.answers.map((answer, i) =>
                            <div key={answer.id} className="form-group row">
                                <div className="form-check">
                                    <input onChange={this.handleOnChange} ref={elm => this.setIndeterminate(elm, answer.value)} value={answer.value} className="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id={answer.id} name={answer.id} />
                                    <label className="form-check-label" htmlFor={answer.id}>
                                        {answer.title}
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        )}
                    </div>
                )}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Question;
```

How is that possible of happening since as you can see I am already setting the value of intermediate to either true or false?

> **SOLUTION**

I removed that `setIndeterminate` function, and did this inside `ref` in input element:

```
<input onChange={this.handleOnChange} ref={elm => {
    if (elm) {
        elm.checked = (answer.value !== '') ? answer.value : false;
        elm.indeterminate = (answer.value === '') ? true : false;
    }
}} value={answer.value} className="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id={answer.id} name={answer.id} />
```

I guess the problem whas that I needed to add that `if (elm)` to check that first.

Comment: Cay you please share complete question.jsx file ?

Comment: @SahilArora just added it.

Comment: https://www.w3.org/TR/2014/WD-html51-20140617/forms.html#checkbox-state-(type=checkbox)

Comment: @hamedhossani so how am i supposed to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution [here](https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-checkbox-indeterminate/) (Thanks to ROBIN WIERUCH for this awesome article ) and works fine for me:

We want to extend the functionality of this checkbox for handling a tri state instead of a bi state. First, we need to transform our state from a boolean to an enum, because only this way we can create a tri state:

```
const CHECKBOX_STATES = {
  Checked: 'Checked',
  Indeterminate: 'Indeterminate',
  Empty: 'Empty',
};
```

and  now we can use it in pur component:

```js
const Checkbox = ({ label, value, onChange }) => {
  const checkboxRef = React.useRef();

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (value === CHECKBOX_STATES.Checked) {
      checkboxRef.current.checked = true;
      checkboxRef.current.indeterminate = false;
    } else if (value === CHECKBOX_STATES.Empty) {
      checkboxRef.current.checked = false;
      checkboxRef.current.indeterminate = false;
    } else if (value === CHECKBOX_STATES.Indeterminate) {
      checkboxRef.current.checked = false;
      checkboxRef.current.indeterminate = true;
    }
  }, [value]);

  return (
    <label>
      <input ref={checkboxRef} type="checkbox" onChange={onChange} />
      {label}
    </label>
  );
};
```